# Web-based configurable DB using Microsoft products

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database-schema

I'm looking for a method or a platform that I can build on that would allow for the configuration of a dynamic DB from web-based configuration pages rather than having to hard code the DB tables in the back end. I offer an example:

I have an asp.net app with a DB.  In that DB I want to put a table that tracks the following attributes:

- Field1 = 80 char field
- Field2 = date field
- Field3 = Text area

Currently I have to manually create a new table directly in my SQL DB with 4 columns: Autonumber ID field, Char field, Date Field, Long Text field.

I would like to have a backend web page in my asp.net app where I could do the following through .Net web pages alone without having to touch the DB directly:

- Create a table called TABLE1 with the Char field, the Date field, and the Text field (the ID field would be created automatically)
- Add fields to this table at any time through the back end .Net web pages.
- Add relationships between fields/tables.

I'd prefer to use a Microsoft product/functionality to allow for this dynamic DB creation and administration as it would allow me to give more power to my users and mean that I wouldn't have to hard code everything directly in the DB. I know this is possible because I can see it being used by large companies like Salesforce.com. Any direction on books, products/platforms or techniques on how this can be accomplished on a smaller scale?

Comment: Why not just use SSMS connected to your production server? Or something like MyLittleAdmin?

Comment: Have you tried to google for "web based sql query tool"? There seem to be at least few differnt solutions available.